# How does this sfrw(x,x_) macro work (msp430)?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, interrupt, msp430

I just ran into an interesting phenomenon with msp430f5529 (TI launchpad). After trying different approaches I was able to find a solution, but I don't understand what is going on here.

This code is part of a timer interrupt service routine (ISR). The special function register (SFR) **TA0IV** is supposed to hold the value of the interrupt number that triggered the ISR.

```
1    unsigned int index;
2
3    index = TA0IV; // Gives wrong value: 19874
4    index = *((volatile unsigned int *) TA0IV_); // Correct value: 4
```

TA0IV is defined with macros here:

```
5    #define sfrw_(x,x_) volatile __MSPGCC_PERIPHERAL__ unsigned int x __asm__("__" #x)
6    #define sfrw(x,x_) extern sfrw_(x,x_)
7    #define TA0IV_                0x036E    /* Timer0_A5 Interrupt Vector Word */
8    sfrw(TA0IV, TA0IV_);
```

1. What does this part of the first macro on line 5 do?

   **asm**("__" #x)
2. Why is there no "x_" on the right hand side in the macro on line 5?
3. Last and most important question: Why does the usual typecasting on line 4 work as expected, but the one on line 3 doesn't?

BTW I use gcc-4.7.0.

---

#### Edit: More info

```
9    #define __MSPGCC_PERIPHERAL__ __attribute__((__d16__))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The # is a preprocessor "stringify" operator.  You can see the impact of this using the -E compiler switch.  Google "c stringify" for details.

2) Couldn't say.  It isn't *required* that all parameters get used, and apparently whoever wrote this decided they didn't need it.

3) I'll take a shot at this one, but since I don't have all the source code or the hardware and can't experiment, I probably won't get it quite right.  Maybe close enough for what you need though.

The first thing to understand is what the asm bit is doing.  Normally (ok, sometimes) when you declare a variable (foo), the compiler assigns its own 'internal' name to the variable (ie _foo).  However, when interfacing with asm modules (or other languages), sometimes you need to be able to specify the exact name to use, not allowing the compiler to mangle it in any fashion.  That's what this asm is doing (see [Asm Labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html)).  So when you brush aside all the #define nonsense, what you've got is:

```
extern volatile __MSPGCC_PERIPHERAL__ unsigned int TA0IV __asm__("__TA0IV");
```

Since the definition you have posted is "extern," presumably somewhere (not shown), there's a symbol named __TA0IV that's getting defined.  And since accessing it isn't working right, it appears that it is getting MIS-defined.

With the caveat that I HAVEN'T TRIED THIS, I would find this to be somewhat more readable:

```
#define TA0IV_                0x036E

inline int ReadInterruptNumber()
{
   int retval;
   asm volatile("movl (%c1), %0": "=rm" (retval) : "i" (TA0IV_));
   return retval;
}
```

FWIW.

Comment: 2) The 2nd value of the macro holds the actual address (0x036E) of the special function register and for sure is not ignored. These sfrw macros are beeing used for practically every SFR and in most cases they work as expected (also see the edit of my original post).

Comment: As you yourself observed, x_ "doesn't appear to the right." You can check yourself by compiling with -E. I just don't see any "0x036E" in the output. The MSGPCC thing apparently just affects the length of the variable. Since this works elsewhere, that suggests elsewhere is linked with a correct definition of __TA0IV. As I mentioned, the code above defines it as 'extern.' Given that this code uses 'asm' to create the symbol name, that suggests the extern is defined in assembly code. The question then is why doesn't your code find that same (working) symbol? Missing dependency?